# Formulating absolute values as linear programming models

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, absolute-value

If we have multiple absolute values, how do we proceed to solve the problem by reformulating as a linear programming model?

F.ex assume we have the following problem:

Minimize $x_1 + 2|2x_2 + 5|$

Subject to: $|x_1 + 4| - |4x_2| \le 7$

In first glance, i would assume we would need to assign x, t, z for the positive and negative values, and reformulate them under the constraint , but not completely sure - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $|x|$ is equal $x$ when $x\geq 0$ and $-x$ when $x<0$.
So each abs splits into two separate cases, constrained by these two inequalities. You have 3 abs, that will give $2^3 = 8$ possible cases, depending on which abs arguments are positive and which are negative. Tough maybe there are easier er ways to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot solve it as an LP because the feasible region is not convex.  For example, $(4,1)$ and $(4,-1)$ are both feasible, but $(4,0)$ is not.

But you can consider the two cases $x_2 \ge 0$ and $x_2 \le 0$ separately, avoiding the $|4x_2|$.  Each of these two cases can be linearized, with only one additional variable, and solved as an LP.  One yields objective value $-1$, and the other yields objective value $-21$, so the smaller value $\min(-1,-21)=-21$ is optimal.

Comment: In principle, as long as we can rephrase the problem as minimizing or maximizing a linear function, we can avoid splitting up the feasible region by just taking the convex hull. But we'd need to find an inequality description of that convex hull, and it would take some work to do that systematically.

Comment: No, the convex hull here is $\mathbb{R}^2$, and the resulting problem would be unbounded.

Comment: Yes, this has to be done *after* we convert the objective function to something linear. If we're minimizing or maximizing a linear $c^Tx$, then we can't introduce any better solutions by taking the convex hull, because a convex combination of points can never be strictly better than all of those points. That's not true for the objective function $x_1 + 2|2x_2+5|$.

Comment: OK, I thought your comment was intended to be applied to this particular problem.

Comment: We can do that here: rewrite this problem as $\min \{ x_1 + 2x_3 \text{s.t.} x_3 \ge 2x_2 + 5, x_3 \ge -2x_2 - 5, |x_1 + 4|-|4x_2| \ge 7\}$ and *now* we can take the convex hull (in $\mathbb R^3$).

Comment: Hmm, if you solve over the convex relaxation, the solver might return a solution that is not feasible to the original constraints.  You are right that the optimal objective value would be the same, but there would be no incentive to be feasible.

Comment: Thank you for the input guys - indeed, we cannot solve it as LP so I tried what @RobPratt mentioned. Cheers!